# What can I use to keep my daughter from falling off the bed?

Tags: bedroom

I've tried using pillows on each side of the mattress but they just don't stay put. I've tried rolling/folding up extra comforters but they unfold and fall off the bed.

Any suggestions as to what I can use at the ends of the mattress to prevent this from happening?

She has a twin size bed, no poles or backboard. She takes up almost half of the bed. Not sure how far the bed is off the ground, I would have to measure that.

Comment: I would consider a full size bed. Seems like she might be a little to big for a twin if she toss and turns a bit.

Comment: Most bedrails have a choking risk attached so be careful . Also, have you added the pillows under the sheets. They still slip but less so and more slowly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case anyone doesn't have the budget for a suitable bedrail, cheaper alternatives are:

- Buy a couple of swimming pool noodles and put them along the edges of the bed under the sheet. The sheet does need to be a fitted one (and fairly tight fitting) to hold them in place but it works well.
- Put pillows or a rolled up duvet on the floor - rather than preventing her falling out in the first place, it simply ensures she doesn't hurt herself if she does fall out

Comment: This seems to be a much cheaper alternative!

Answer (score 8):

You can use a **bed rail**, which is a board or rail mounted on the side of the bed frame. Think of it as a removable headboard for the sides of the bed.

Here's a general purpose one that you can buy commercially:

[image]

Alternatively, you can make your own pretty easily. Just get a board of wood and prop it between the side of the mattress and the bed frame.

Comment: I would avoid building your own bed rail.  When it comes to children's safety  products, there are often "hidden" risks that it is difficult to recognize when building one that commercial producers of thousands recognize and avoid.  For example, leaving too much room between adjacent slats.

Answer (score 2):

For very cheap (like possibly under $30), if you already have a drill and saw, you could simply use some 2 x 4's, screws, and create your own railings.

Depending on size of bed this would probably take anywhere from 4-8 8ft 2x4's and at least 14 screws (***or I guess even wood glue could work so no screws or drill needed***).

The 3 horizontal 2x4's that connect the side rails to each other would be placed between the mattress and the bed bottom. I don't think there'd be much comfort-ability issues with this as long as the mattress is decent enough.

You'd want to make sure that the side rails are pretty tight/close to the mattress on each side, so not much any room for sliding issues.

You could even paint/stain/finish the piece to make it look however you prefer.

[image]

Comment: I would avoid building your own bed rail. When it comes to children's safety products, there are often "hidden" risks that it is difficult to recognize when building one that commercial producers of thousands recognize and avoid. For example, leaving too much room between adjacent slats.